# An exercise in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, $\phi$ be a pure state and $L=\{a\in A:\phi(a^{\ast}a)=0\}$, how to prove that $L+L^*\subseteq ker\phi$. ($L^*=\{a^{\ast}: a\in L\}$)

I think it is an easy exercise, but......could someone show me the answer or just give me some hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $L\subset\ker\phi$, if $a\in L$ then by Kadison's inequality
$$
0\leq|\phi(a)|^2=\phi(a)^*\phi(a)\leq\phi(a^*a)=0,
$$
so $\phi(a)=0$. And now for $b\in L^*$, then $b^*\in L$, so $\phi(b)=\overline{\phi(b^*)}=0$ (this last part is just the fact that the kernel of a selfadjoint functional contains adjoints; it is an ideal, in fact).

Comment: Is this inequality $\phi(a)^{\ast} \phi(a) \leq \phi(a^{\ast}a)$ always true for a pure state $\phi$? I only know that this inequality is correct for contractive completely positive linear function $\phi$.

Comment: A state is a contractive completely positive map.

Comment: :Thanks for your patient answer again. :)